# MSBuild is not passing logger parameters to the custom logger

Tags: logging, msbuild

I created a custom logger that derives from the `Logger` class and was able to attach it to MSBuild. Everything seems to work except I can't pass any parameters to the logger. The command line I am using to run MSBuild:

`msbuild Sample.proj /noconsolelogger /l:CustomLogger,MSBuildCustomLogger.dll;param1=value1;param2=value2`

I am overriding the `Initialize(IEventSource eventSource)` for the logger as follows:

```cs
public override void Initialize(IEventSource eventSource)
{
    try
    {
        InitializeParameters();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new LoggerException("Unable to initialize the logger", e);
    }
}
```

And the `InitializeParameters()` will use the `Parameters` property from `Logger` to parse the given parameters. But the `Parameters` property is always `null` at this point. So it led me to think MSBuild does not set the `Parameters` string. How can I pass the logger parameters to the custom logger? I would appreciate any help / hints regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter should be the log file name:

```
l:CustomLogger,MSBuildCustomLogger.dll;custom.log;param1=value1;param2=value2
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I am actually deriving from the `Logger` class not from the `FileLogger` so I don't think I need to pass any log file name. Plus it is just that any parameter beyond the assembly name doesn't get through to the logger.

Comment: Try comparing your code with [other logger implementations](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=MSBuild+logger&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)